# Get WooCommerce shipping methods programmatically

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

How can I retrieve the shipping methods in my WooCommerce shop? I have this on my checkout page:

[image: my checkout page]

And inside my admin it looks like this:

[image: shipping methods in wp admin]

I have tried doing:

```
WC()->shipping->load_shipping_methods()
```

But it does not return GLS or Click and collect text / price. It returns this data: https://paste.laravel.io/0c1aff96-dbed-452c-856f-6d62b6f1f47e

Comment: What output do you get when using WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods(); ?

Comment: @L7c1f3r the same output as in the pastebin..

Comment: I have now tested this and indeed, the same result. If I look at your output and compare it to mine, I see that the data is present, but for example 'GLS' is missing as method_title, but 'Flat rate' is shown there, but this is the same with my output, so there's nothing wrong with that. 'GLS', 
turns out to be the label. What is your ultimate intention, what data do you want to retrieve and where do you want to use it afterwards?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use something different as following *(commented)*:

```
// Loop through shipping packages from WC_Session (They can be multiple in some cases)
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_id => $package ) {
    // Check if a shipping for the current package exist
    if ( WC()->session->__isset( 'shipping_for_package_'.$package_id ) ) {
        // Loop through shipping rates for the current package
        foreach ( WC()->session->get( 'shipping_for_package_'.$package_id )['rates'] as $shipping_rate_id => $shipping_rate ) {
            $rate_id     = $shipping_rate->get_id(); // same thing that $shipping_rate_id variable (combination of the shipping method and instance ID)
            $method_id   = $shipping_rate->get_method_id(); // The shipping method slug
            $instance_id = $shipping_rate->get_instance_id(); // The instance ID
            $label_name  = $shipping_rate->get_label(); // The label name of the method
            $cost        = $shipping_rate->get_cost(); // The cost without tax
            $tax_cost    = $shipping_rate->get_shipping_tax(); // The tax cost
            $taxes       = $shipping_rate->get_taxes(); // The taxes details (array)
        }
    }
}
```

> Now **if customer session is not yet enabled** *(customer hasn't add to cart any product yet)*, you need to **force WooCommerce customer session activation** using the following:
>
> ```
> // Enable customer WC_Session
> add_action( 'init', 'wc_session_enabler' );
> function wc_session_enabler() {
>     if ( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
>         return;
>
>     if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
>         WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

If needed, you can also **get the customer chosen shipping method(s)** with the following:

```
$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
```

Comment: Do you know if WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ); still works if there is only one shipping method available?

Comment: @SamAssoum Yes it does work …

Comment: I want to display the selected shipping method to the My Order section which I made custom, So how can I print the selected shipping method in session print to My Order section?